# Symfony 404 not found

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I'm new to symfony.

I did:

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
rm -rf app/logs/*
```

Then:

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:user :rwx app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:user:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

`ls -al` gives:

```
drwxrwxrwx 3 user user  1024 мая   29 00:06 cache(cache is on green background)
drwxrwxrwx 2 user user  1024 мая   29 00:06 logs(logs is on green background)
```

Now i'm trying to access /Symfony/web/app_dev.php - It shows:

An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found).

Do you want to open the profiler?

When i click OK, it redirect to

```
/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/bd8604738ac7af3c9d0611ea12076f0f62422601
```

and 404 file not found..

This is app/logs/dev.log

```
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] request.INFO: Matched route "_welcome" (parameters: "_controller": "Acme\DemoBundle\Controller\WelcomeController::indexAction", "_route": "_welcome") [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Fragment\FragmentHandler::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DeprecationLoggerListener::injectLogger". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ChromePhpHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\CacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Fragment\FragmentHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-05-29 00:12:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
```

I've not found an solution, please help

Edit:

Routing_dev.xml

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index }

_demo_secured:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/SecuredController.php"
    type:     annotation

_demo:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/DemoController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /demo

_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

config_dev.xml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:   { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml" }
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
        firephp:
            type:  firephp
            level: info
        chromephp:
            type:  chromephp
            level: info

assetic:
    use_controller: true

#swiftmailer:
#    delivery_address: me@example.com
```

app_dev.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

// If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup for more information
//umask(0000);

// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: what if you run the `config.php` file?

Comment: did it work (once)? Blind guessing: is mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: no errors when running config.php - I didnt set up anything ike mod_rewrite.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem if you set up another fresh symfony project?

Answer (score 10):

My problem was that [`kernel.terminate`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-terminate-event) event was executing for more than 10 seconds. It was very hard to spot, because profiler was not measuring timeline for this event.

When I realised this, I immediately narrowed the problem down to one of my event listeners having abnormally long running `__construct` method. This delayed profile file printing for too long, which caused a Javascript timeout error after 5 retries.

After fixing the offending listener, `kernel.terminate` event went fast and the problem was gone immediately.

You can quickly see your attached listeners using `bin/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.terminate`.

Comment: well, you saved me days of my life.

Answer (score 6):

According to my own experience; this behavior happens when you change the standard behavior of your routes. For example, in my case I was using kernel.request listener to create a language detection mechanism which supposed  pick the best possible language for the user based on her/his browsers supported language.

I was using {_locale} prefix in all my routes located in app/config/routing.yml

```
some_route:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/
```

This way I was able to quickly add at the beginning of my routes the language code and in my listener class I was redirecting the client to a route prefixed with an existing language code regardless the client requested the route with or without the locale.

For example, if my site had only "en" and "de" as languages and if the user requested

```
http://www.mysite.com/somepage
```

or

```
http://www.mysite.com/fr/somepage
```

I was redirecting the client to

```
http://www.mysite.com/en/somepage
```

So whenever there was an error in my application the profiler route was unaware of this situation and was trying to show itself from a route that has no {_locale} prefixed. And this was causing a 404 error.

The solution was simple:

I opened the app/config/routing_dev.yml file and modified the all the routes as below:

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/_configurator
```

Notice the /{_locale} part.

So the problem is fixed for me.

Answer (score 1):

What ended up working for me was increasing the values for `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` in my php.ini file, restarting php-fpm (e.g., `brew services restart php56`), and then restarting the server (`sudo nginx -s reload`). If it still doesn't work after all of that, try restarting your computer. It worked for a coworker of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you haven't included the routes for the web profiler?

If you post your `config_dev.yml` & `routing_dev.yml` maybe we can see what is wrong.

Your `routing_dev.yml` should look something like this

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

Your `config_dev.yml` should contain this

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
    - { resource: security_dev.yml }

framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
```

Also make sure `app_dev.php` is setting the environment to `dev` like so

```
// ...
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
// ...
```

Comment: added the data that the files contains, please look at it

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a route conflict . I changed the routes in routing_dev.yml in a way that is not in conflict with my routes