# Symfony profiler throws 404

Tags: php, symfony, profiler

I've created new project in symfony and I get an error prompt on each site:

> An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found).
>   Do you want to open the profiler?

When I open the profiler there is a message

> Token not found
>   Token "59942c" was not found in the database.

Moreover, in the cache directory the profiler directory is empty! I checked permissions and they're proper. I tried `cache:clear` and removing cache manually, but that didn't help.

Comment: Mati, there is an answer for you below, waiting for some days. If you found it helpful, and it resolved your problem, please consider accepting it. To do so, click the tick mark to the left of the answer, so it turns green. Alternatively, you are quite free to supply your own answer, if you found a different solution. You may "self accept" that if you wish. Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it in this answer (related to long running `kernel.terminate` event): https://stackoverflow.com/a/34048364/118593

Comment: the usefull thing to do is run  ```php app/console debug:event-dispatcher```

Comment: max małecki, that is very good answer! this command may show you potential errors within events.

Answer (score 64):

It's often problem with event subscriber/listener.
Try run

```
console debug:event
```

And check for errors

Comment: How do you *"check for errors"* ? Having a [hard time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57143819/symfony-4-app-works-with-docker-compose-but-breaks-with-docker-swarm-no-login)...

Comment: @AymDev: In this case, you "check for errors" by looking for any thrown exception or error message in the output. If the command exits cleanly then event subscribers/listeners are probably not the issue.

Answer (score 7):

This usually happens if the cache directory is not properly set up to allow the web servers' user to write data into them.

Under Linux, I would usually use this for development:

```
php app/console --env=dev cache:clear
php app/console --env=dev cache:warmup
chmod -R a+rwX app/cache/
setfacl -Rm g:www-data:rwX app/cache/
setfacl -Rm g:dev-user:rwX app/cache/
```

This ensures all required directories will be created and then assigned the required permissions. If you do not have ACL enabled, skip the `setfacl` commands.

OFC, replace `www-data` with your web servers' username, and `dev-user` with your username.

Comment: I have checked the cache directories permissions, and even tried using the database instead of the filesystem for storing profiler data, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @IanPhillips You should check the `app/logs/dev.log` file while loading the page, there will probably some errors appearing there, like some missing classes.

Comment: Interesting. I checked dev.log and actually found a missing class in one of my YAML files. Now I started seeing profiles for `new JsonResponse(...)` ajax calls, but not for normal responses. Progress!

Comment: Setting `{'maxTries': 100}` and waiting for a while, is started seeing all profiles. I suspect this is because I'm using Vagrant over NFS (mac). Will look into this for solution.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, it was caused because was using Apache without an `.htaccess` file.

If you are using Apache locally or on your server you can install Apache Pack to automatically generate an `.htaccess` file:

`composer require symfony/apache-pack`

> This pack installs a .htaccess file in the public/ directory that contains the rewrite rules needed to serve the Symfony application.
> https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes, on big projects (custom Sylius app in my case), profiler data generates very slowly.

Symfony checks things only 5 times each 1000 ms, so if data was not generated during 5 seconds - you will get `An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar`.

To understand whether this is a case - open _wdt url at new tab - if it 404, but after some time - 10-15-30 seconds it become 200 - then this is a case.

To fix this, you should override `vendor/symfony/web-profiler-bundle/Resources/views/Profiler/base_js.html.twig` (to `templates/bundles/WebProfilerBundle/Profiler/base_js.html.twig`) and replace `{ maxTries: 5 }` to `{ maxTries: 30 }`.

After that, script will be trying to get profiler / web debug toolbar page for 30 seconds which hopefully will be enough for your app to generate profiler data:

[image: Finally 200 after bunch of 404s]

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11015) in the profiler. Since Symfony 2.4, the profiler persisting the data used by the WDT is the very last thing done by Symfony.

The alert you see means that the profiler has not been able to find the token requested in the 2500ms allowed, However if you click OK in the alert, you should be redirected to the profiler and figure out what precisely is slow.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after upgrading Symfony 2.3->2.6. After upgrading `web/app_dev.php` it fixed the issue. I believe you need the `Debug::enable();` line.

Answer (score 1):

Need .htaccess file for Apache. I am not sure, why there is no default in Symfony like Laravel. This one if copy from Laravel and help with this problem, too.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue after upgrading 2.6 -> 2.8 on a 2.4 era project. Got a `useMicrosecondTimestamps` error with the node layer. Fixed by nuking `rm -r app/cache/*`. @marenkay's method did not clear the node-php server cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit or add your htacces file like this

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not 
  resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

# Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
# If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
# project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
# resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
# work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
# the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

# Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
# (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
# rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
# endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
# redirect -> request -> ...).
# So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
# to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
# environment variable, you have 2 choices:
# - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
# - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
#   following RewriteCond (best solution)
  RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
  RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

# If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
# We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
  RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_alias.c>
    # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
    # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
    # and the generated links can still be used.
    RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
    # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you explain which changes are needed and why?

Comment: this is more or less (depends on the version) what comes with _composer require symfony/apache-pack_ (see: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#adding-rewrite-rules or https://github.com/symfony/recipes/issues/190). it's also the main result of all recipes found via google.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not get 404 every time, but periodically and use docker at the same time, then you should check that you do not have conflicts with the containers accepting requests. In my case, several projects were launched with the same name "fpm" and, of course, only one of them had a real token

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. But in my case the serialization in the `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\FileProfilerStorage::write()` required to much memory.

After increasing PHP's memory limit to `256M`, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was due to a bad configuration of a route. That route had the string "/{slug}" and this conflicted with some URLs, such as the one for the profiler. It was enough to add a differentiating string "/article/{slug}".