# Symfony 4 app works with Docker Compose but breaks with Docker Swarm (no login, profiler broken)

Tags: symfony, docker, authentication, symfony4, docker-swarm

I'm using **Docker Compose** locally with:

- *app* container: **Nginx** & **PHP-FPM** with a **Symfony 4** app
- **PostgreSQL** container
- **Redis** container

It works great locally but when deployed to the development **Docker Swarm** cluster, I can't login to the Symfony app.
The Swarm stack is the same as local, except for *PostgreSQL* which is installed on its own server (not a Docker container).

Using the *profiler*, I nearly always get the following error:

> **Token not found**
>   Token "2df1bb" was not found in the database.

When I display the content of the `var/log/dev.log` file, I get these lines about my login attempts:

```
[2019-07-22 10:11:14] request.INFO: Matched route "app_login". {"route":"app_login","route_parameters":{"_route":"app_login","_controller":"App\\Controller\\SecurityController::login"},"request_uri":"http://dev.ip/public/login","method":"GET"} []
[2019-07-22 10:11:14] security.DEBUG: Checking for guard authentication credentials. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticators":1} []
[2019-07-22 10:11:14] security.DEBUG: Checking support on guard authenticator. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginFormAuthenticator"} []
[2019-07-22 10:11:14] security.DEBUG: Guard authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginFormAuthenticator"} []
[2019-07-22 10:11:14] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
```

The only thing I may find useful here is the `Guard authenticator does not support the request.` message, but I have no idea what do search from there.

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is my `docker-compose.dev.yml` *(removed redis container and changed app environment variables)*:

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
    web:
        driver: overlay

services:
    # Symfony + Nginx
    app:
        image: "registry.gitlab.com/my-image"
        deploy:
            replicas: 2
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
        networks:
            - web
        ports:
          - 80:80
        environment:
            APP_ENV: dev
            DATABASE_URL: pgsql://user:pass@0.0.0.0/my-db
            MAILER_URL: gmail://user@gmail.com:pass@localhost
```

Here is the `Dockerfile.dev` used to build the **app** image on development servers:

```
# Base image
FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine

# Source code into:
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Import Symfony + Composer
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data ./symfony .
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Alpine Linux packages + PHP extensions
RUN apk update && apk add \
        supervisor \
        nginx \
        bash \
        postgresql-dev \
        wget \
        libzip-dev zip \
        yarn \
        npm \
    && apk --no-cache add pcre-dev ${PHPIZE_DEPS} \
    && pecl install redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && composer install \
        --prefer-dist \
        --no-interaction \
        --no-progress \
    && yarn install \
    && npm rebuild node-sass \
    && yarn encore dev \
    && mkdir -p /run/nginx

# Nginx conf + Supervisor entrypoint
COPY ./dev.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./.htpasswd /etc/nginx/.htpasswd
COPY ./supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf

EXPOSE 80 443

ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**
I `pull`ed my **Docker** images and ran the application using only the `docker-compose.dev.yml` (without the `docker-compose.local.yml` that I'd use too locally). I have been able to login, everything is okay.

So... It works with **Docker Compose** *locally*, but not in **Docker Swarm** on a remote server.

---

**UPDATE 3:**
I made the dev server leave the *Swarm cluster* and started the services using **Docker Compose**. It works.

The issue is about going from **Compose** to **Swarm**. I created an issue: [docker/swarm #2956](https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/2956)

Comment: This is your `App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator->supports($request)` which causes this problem. What's inside?

Comment: @Roukmoute it only checks if the route is `app_login` and the method `POST`. According to the logs the `GET` method is used but in the profiler I could see the POST data.

Comment: I am astonished that your log do not show the POST data. Your POST is in HTML standard or in javascript?

Comment: @Roukmoute I fear something's definitely broken with my dev environment.. HTML standard, just a basic login form, most of the auth system have been generated by the `make:auth` command from Maker bundle. As I said, the profiler seems broken too, I think there may be a huge issue with the configuration but I have no idea where to look. The login form is probably just a consequence of the issue

Comment: So update your post with your configuration of docker-compose and all of its dependencies

Comment: @Roukmoute Updated. I added the **Dockerfile** too. I hate doing such long posts but if it helps... You can ask me anything about the config. Thanks for the time you take.

Comment: Are you using the same database instance locally and on Swarm?

Comment: @PierreB. I use a **PostgreSQL** Docker image locally and a database server for development.

Comment: Are you using the exact same dat? (i.e. trying to copy the buggy database content into your local one)

Comment: @PierreB. No, the database data is set using Doctrine ORM *Fixtures*. But they use the same fixtures.

Comment: I think (part of) your issue might come from that: databases may not be consistent between your local environment and Swarm. Try to export the Swarm database content and import it in your environment, if you reproduce the issue that will help you fix it

Comment: @PierreB. I have been able to use the development database (during my *"update 2"*), which is not part of the Swarm btw. The app ran locally and connected to the pgsql server correctly, I could logged in. To reproduce the issue, do you think I should try to reproduce the Swarm cluster locally ? Not sure what I'd get. I have ssh access to the swarm manager if needed.

Comment: Could it be related to the domain and/or cookies?

Comment: @DiogoSgrillo I don't understand how but if you have any ideas feel free to share.

Comment: I don't know the exact problem, but I have some ideas for you to try to find out:
1. change the `APP_DEV` to `local` instead of `dev` in your docker-compose.dev.yml file for now to see if you get the same error, if not, then it's the environment problem. Possibliliteis: 
 - config_dev.yml file
 - if .htaccess file is used to use app_dev.php, then check both .htaccess and app_dev.php file  
2. check the log file path you define in your nginx conf file to view the access log and error log to see if there is permission or other issue there. 
3. the `DATEBADE_URL` parameter might be the prob.

Comment: (didn't have enough space in the last comment.)
4. you could try to exec into one of the containers in the swarm and connect to your postgres db from there manually, if that doesn't even work, then there is a problem with the firewall or network.

Comment: Hi @DeyiKong I use `APP_ENV` with `dev` value locally too, tried changing it to `local` without success. There's no `.htaccess`, the `.htpasswd` is for dev server auth and is working fine (I log in), the logs only show bot attempts to login, no error on my usage. I exec'ed into the app container and executed a **DQL** query with `bin/console doctrine:query:dql`, worked fine too. It's driving me crazy lol thanks for your help !

Comment: @DeyiKong also, there is no `app_dev.php`, it's a **Symfony 4** app, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not your specific case, but it could help some user who have problems using Docker Swarm which are not present in Docker Compose.

I've been fighting this issue for over a week. I found that the default network for Docker Compose uses the *bridge* driver and Docker Swarm uses *Overlay*.

Later, I read in the *Caveats* section in the [Postgres Docker image repo](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) that there's a poblem with the IPVS connection timeouts in overlay networks and it refers to [this blog](https://success.mirantis.com/article/ipvs-connection-timeout-issue) for solutions.

I try with the first option and changed the [endpoint_mode](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#endpoint_mode) setting to `dnsrr` in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
db:
    image: postgres:12
    # Others settings ...
    deploy:
        endpoint_mode: dnsrr
```

Keep in mind that there are some caveats (mentioned in the blog) to consider. However, you could try the other options.

Also in [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37466) maybe you find something useful as they faced the same problem.